# R ggplotly: legend is not correctly displayed

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I do have a problem with `plotly` package. The legend does not display correctly or does not show all the values cause it is cut!

[image]

I would like to get the legend outside of the plot area (at the bottom or right corner).

I have already tried to change the position in `ggplot`:

```
legend.position="bottom"
```

no result at all...

then i have tried code from `plotly` website:

```
p %>% layout(legend = list(x = 0.5, y = -100))
```

it did not work, the legend was at the bottom, but it was cut, and behind x axis title...

Here is a sample code from `mtcars` dataset:

```
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
  geom_boxplot()

ggplotly(a)
```

as we can see the title of the legend is cut there as well..

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could play with the margin and plot size. You can try:

```
m = list(
  l = 100,
  r = 40,
  b = 100,
  t = 50,
  pad = 0
)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T), y = mpg,fill = interaction(cyl, carb, lex.order = T))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
a %>% layout(autosize = F, width = 800, height = 600, margin = m)
```

Comment: Hey, it did work! Thanks a lot! For the Info i used: `m = list(
  l = 80,
  r = 300,
  b = 80,
  t = 100,
  pad = 0
)`